# Script that checks GCloud project before deploy

Tags: shell, gcloud

So today I basically fumbled a huge amount of traffic because I deployed a gcloud project while having the wrong project set. As you know, when we deploy to gcloud we have to make sure we choose the right project using `gcloud config set project [PROJECT_NAME]`, unfortunately this is sometimes hard to remember to do as multiple projects require quick deployments to be sent out when bugs arise.

I was wondering if anyone had a good solution for this that runs a predeploy shell script which makes sure that you are deploying the right project when deploying.

Thanks in advance,
Nikita

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ajordat's answer is good but I think there's a simpler solution.

If you **unset** the default project, then you'll be required to explicitly set `--project=${PROJECT}` on each `gcloud` command.

```sh
gcloud config unset project
```

Then, every `gcloud` command will require:

```sh
gcloud ... --project=${PROJECT} ...
```

This **doesn't** inhibit specifying an incorrect `${PROJECT}` value in the commands but it does encourage a more considered approach.

A related approach is to define configurations (sets of properties) and to enable these before running commands. IMO this is problematic too and I recommend unsetting `gcloud config` properties and always being explicit.

See:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/configurations

Comment: this is perfect

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy), the `gcloud` tool has some flags that are independent of the subcommand (`app deploy`) that is being used, such as `--account`, `--verbosity` or `--log-http`. One of these gcloud-wide flags is `--project`, which will let you specify the project you are deploying to.

Now, to deploy you **must** use a project, in your case since you have to deploy to different projects you must specify it somewhere. There's no workaround to specifying the project because the service must have somewhere to be deployed to. You have two options:

- You can set the default project to the one you want to use:

  ```
  gcloud config set project <project-name>
  gcloud app deploy
  ```

  Notice that you would have to set the project back again to the one you were previously using.
- Or you can use the `--project` flag in order to specify where to deploy.

  ```
  gcloud app deploy --project=<project-name>
  ```

I would recommend you to use the `--project` flag as it's more deployment specific and doesn't involve changing the default project. Moreover, you can keep working on the previous project ID since it doesn't change the default values, it's just a deploy to another project.

Notice that in the past you could specify the project on the `app.yaml` file with the [`application`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#application) tag, but this was deprecated in favor of the `--project` flag.